# Regular expression alphabet, numbers - some character

Tags: regex

I am forcing user to write username based on some rules as follows:

```
   - alpha start
   - alpha, numerals included
   - exclude I, L , O, Q, 0, 1, 7
```

I tried something like [a-hA-Hj-kJ-Km-nM-nNpPr-zR-z2-689]

But I know it is not good or may be wrong, suggest

Please re should consider both smaller and capital case exclusion

Comment: Why those exclusions? That seems bizarre.

Comment: @joonty: Potential homoglyphs, I guess.

Comment: actually they are for some other purpose also to avoid typing mistake

Comment: @jam but you can't account for users' behaviours or memories anyway, so why expend this extra effort?

Comment: i 1, o 0, I 1, O 0 , these are some pair to hard to guess. Actually i am generating random password.Overall I am creating re to identify string containing above rule

Comment: @joy, After reading wikipedia about homoglyphs , i think I need more pair and character in above exclusion list, thanks

Comment: Q also look like O, and if i rotate 7 , it can create same case [ I am playing purely safe]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could suit your needs:

```
^[a-zA-Z&&[^iIlLoOqQ]][a-zA-Z0-9&&[^iIlLoOqQ017]]*$
```

`[X&&[^Y]]` means *"X but not Y"*

**EDIT:** it works in Java at least, since this notation doesn't seem to be managed by every regex flavor...

Comment: That said, I think this is the best answer as it makes it much clearer what characters are actually being excluded - thus making it easier to understand the code!

Comment: @TomLord And it's the first answer I've seen that uses character class subtraction! I was just about to pounce on the opportunity to post this, but too late +1

Comment: An alternative approach would also be to use negative forward lookaheads - which might especially be useful if the regex language being used doesn't support "&&".

Answer (score 2):

What you have is fine, but you would need to start with the alpha character class alone.  You could also do a case insensitive match so there is not so much repetition.

```
^[a-hjkmnpr-z][a-hjkmnpr-z2-689]*$
```

Comment: UP.I agreed with your solution , better approach than I think, but I was trying to find out, will any faster RE possible.